# Exclude the properties of one type from another

Tags: typescript

If I have three types, say, for instance:

```js
interface TestOne {
  a: number;
  b: string;
}

interface TestTwo {
  c: boolean;
}

interface TestThree {
  a: number;
  b: string;
  c: boolean;
}
```

How could I define an interface that is the type `TestThree` without the properties of `TestTwo` (by that I mean, only `a` and `b`).

I appreiate I could use `Exclude`/`Pick` and be specific with the keys I want to use/not-use, but in this instance I'd like to be more general about it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Omit<T, U>` and `keyof` to achieve that:

```js
interface TestOne {
  a: number;
  b: string;
}

interface TestTwo {
  c: boolean;
}

interface TestThree {
  a: number;
  b: string;
  c: boolean;
}

type TestFour = Omit<TestThree, keyof TestTwo>;

const val: TestFour = {
  a: 0,
  b: ''
}
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=21&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5gPIhQbwChlk4AuZEAVwFsAjaAbmOToqylAHNmBfQwqEixEKdFlQB3APbIiJBBTrTpAGwhwQfAUOjwkaTGFQALKBAItylWgyjMSbZB24Pki1ivWbthMAE8ABzEjADFpKihkAF5kbBpgMAAecWMzCwAaZABrCH9pGEMJGQA%20ZkIEaRAsZAA3OFUKVPDImLkrCgAGDJYnAHI%20wl4gA)

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for that, I suspected there was a built in type to cover this, glad to know that one does in fact exist